# Blender View Matrix structure

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, camera

I am trying to use the Blender cycles standalone plugin with the xna app to render scene. But I am stuck as I don't know the structure of the camera matrix. In xna view matrix structure is [this](http://tinyurl.com/mu5px6e) . Can somebody explain the same for  Blender?

Comment: I don't know how you guys are finding it duplicate. I am passing the view matrix, I don't need to retrieve view matrix. Problem is I am  not get expected output with view matrix I am passing. So I want to know what is structure of view matrix ?